# @Configuration class, pass @Bean to other @Bean

Tags: java, spring

Which is the best way to pass/use a `@Bean` type present in the same configuration class to another `@Bean`?
For example if I have the current situation:

```
@Configuration
public ConfigurationSample {

     @Bean("first")
     public CustomType beanA(){

     }

     @Bean("four")
     public CustomType beanD(){

     }

    @Bean("second")
    public OtherCustomType beanB(@Qualifier("first") CustomType bean){
         //Use bean
    }

    @Bean("third")
    public OtherCustomType  beanC(){
       CustomType  bean = beanA();
       ....
       ....
    }

}
```

Should I use the `@Qualifier` annotation or i can directly call the bean or it's equivalent and why?

**EDIT**

Reading responses I added `beanD()` missing before (sorry!) to make more clear the  need of `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: If there is just a single instance, don't use an `@Qualifier` or just call the method from `beanb()` method. Either will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED** after the question edit introducing `beanD`.

Let's make it clear:

- `CustomType beanA` doesn't depend on anything
- `OtherCustomType beanB` depends on `CustomType beanA`
- `OtherCustomType beanC` depends on `CustomType beanA`
- `CustomType beanD` doesn't depend on anything

Therefore all you need to do is:

- To distinguish `OtherCustomType beanB` from `OtherCustomType beanC`
- To distinguish `CustomType beanA` from `CustomType beanD`

... as long as they are of the same type. Autowiring `CustomType beanA` is hence *not* safe without a qualifier. You have two choices:

1. Using `@Qualifier` to autowire a certain bean.
2. Annotating `beanA` with `@Primary` to define the precedence in the autowiring.

The following snippet is the example of the first way (using `@Qualifier`):

```
@Configuration
public ConfigurationSample {

    @Bean("beanA")
    public CustomType beanA() { 
         /** CODE **/ 
    }

    @Bean("beanB")
    public OtherCustomType beanB(@Qualifier("beanA") CustomType beanA) {
         /** USE beanA HERE **/
    }

    @Bean("beanC")
    public OtherCustomType beanC(@Qualifier("beanA") CustomType beanA) {
         /** USE beanA HERE **/
    }

    @Bean("beanD")
    public CustomType beanD(){
        /** CODE **/ 
    }
}
```

To call the method `beanA()` inside the `beanB` and `beanC` body instead of autowiring is safe too.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Qualifier` if you have 2 implementation of the same bean;

```
@Configuration
public ConfigurationSample {

     @Bean("first")
     public CustomType beanA(){
       //
     }

    @Bean("second")
    public CustomType beanB(){
       //
    }

    @Bean("third")
    public OtherCustomType beanC(@Qualifier("first") CustomType bean){
       //Use bean
    }    
}
```

In your case you don't need to use `@Qualifier`

Comment: The `beanB` is of `OtherCustomType` type. You don't need to qualify the `beanA`.

Comment: Actually I try to explain when `@Qualifier` should be used but thanks for correction!

Answer (score 1):

When create more than one bean of the same type and want to wire only one of them with a property. In such cases, you can use the @Qualifier annotation along with @Autowired to remove the confusion by specifying which exact bean will be wired.

As in the xml

```
<!-- Definition for student1 bean -->
   <bean id = "student1" class = "com.test">
      <property name = "name" value = "alpha" />
      <property name = "age" value = "11"/>
   </bean>

<!-- Definition for student2 bean -->
  <bean id = "student2" class = "com.test">
      <property name = "name" value = "beta" />
      <property name = "age" value = "2"/>
  </bean>
```

In the class

```
 public class Profile {
       @Autowired
       @Qualifier("student1")
       private Student student;
    }
```